# After macos update to Macos Sonoma Version 14.0 (23A344) in Apple M1 Pro, Tomcat is crashing with "Out of memory in logging code (P3)" error

Tags: macos, sap-commerce-cloud, macos-sonoma

After macos update to Macos Sonoma Version 14.0 (23A344) in Apple M1 Pro, Tomcat is struck with "Out of memory in logging code (P3)"

SAP Commerce Cloud (hybris) tomcat server is throwing above error and stuck there. Any help here

Answer (score 0):

remove or increase the value of those properties that can limit the java heap size. Search for some of these props in your local.properties file:

1. java.mem
2. for **tomcat.javaoptions** or **tomcat.debugjavaoptions** check the arguments: -Xmx and -Xms

Answer (score 0):

You need to update tanukiwrapper to the ARM-specific one.

You can find the wrapper on the Tanuki website: https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp#stable

In SAP Commerce case the simplest way to update tanukiwrapper is to replace bin/platform/tomcat with tomcat from the newer SAP Commerce version. In my case, I used Tomcat from SAP Commerce 2205. Do not forget about `ant server` before the start after replacement.

Also, you might need to fix the configuration for SOLR.

To increase the stack size add the following line to /solrserver/resources/solr/X.X/server/bin/solr.in.sh

```
SOLR_JAVA_STACK_SIZE='-Xss512k'
```